# Reuse select aliases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query where I'm doing two subqueries to get X, Y data:

```
SELECT
  t.series AS week,
  ( ... ) X,
  ( ..., AND ... ) Y,
  ROUND(( ... ) * 100) / ( ..., AND ... ), 2) Z
FROM series_tmp t
```

Y is kind of subset of X, since I apply just an additional condition to the existing ones, if X is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t2.id = t1.another_id
WHERE t2.something = 1
AND t1.date BETWEEN t.series AND t.series + INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

Then Y has an additional AND condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t2.id = t1.another_id
WHERE t2.something = 1
AND t1.date BETWEEN t.series AND t.series + INTERVAL 6 DAY
AND t1.some_state = 'x state'
```

And for the value of X I need to take those two results - X and Y and do some calculation. Since I can't use the aliases, I have to use a subquery, right? But in that case it seems too much.

Is there a way to reuse those subqueries? It seems to be too much of the same.

`series_tmp` is a temporary table used to create a range of dates with a specific step:

```
CALL generate_series(DATE('2020-08-23' - INTERVAL 12 WEEK), '2020-08-23', 'INTERVAL 7 DAY');

SELECT * FROM series_tmp;

'2020-05-31'
'2020-06-07'
'2020-06-14'
'2020-06-21'
'2020-06-28'
'2020-07-05'
'2020-07-12'
'2020-07-19'
'2020-07-26'
'2020-08-02'
'2020-08-09'
'2020-08-16'
'2020-08-23'
```

The `INNER JOIN` used is the only one in the query which is just used to compare against primary/foreign key to further filter by the value of `t2.something` (`t2.something = 1`).

The columns I'm using from t1 are just `date` and `some_state`, the count is performed using the wildcard.

This is to reproduce the scenario:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t3;
CREATE TABLE t3 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  t3_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  t2_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_at datetime NOT NULL,
  status varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO t3 (name) VALUES ('t3 #1');
INSERT INTO t2 (t3_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t1 (t2_id, status, created_at) VALUES   
('1', 'sent',      '2020-06-03 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-06-08 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-06-19 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-06-26 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-06-27 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-06-30 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-07-08 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-07-09 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-07-14 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-07-21 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-07-22 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-07-25 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-07-30 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-08-02 00:00:00'),
('1', 'sent',      '2020-08-10 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-08-18 00:00:00'),
('1', 'responded', '2020-08-19 00:00:00');

-- expected result would be:

-- '2020-05-31','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-06-07','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-06-14','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-06-21','2','2','100.00'
-- '2020-06-28','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-07-05','2','0','0.00'
-- '2020-07-12','1','1','100.00'
-- '2020-07-19','3','0','0.00'
-- '2020-07-26','1','1','100.00'
-- '2020-08-02','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-08-09','1','0','0.00'
-- '2020-08-16','2','2','100.00'
```

The SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45f389.

I'm using MySQL 5.6 so I'm not able to use CTEs :(

PS: `series_tmp` comes from [this].

Comment: Can you create a view?

Comment: Use your query which calculates `week`, `X` and `Y` as a subquery, calculate `Z` in addition in outer query. Or use conditional counting - `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(t1.some_state = 'x state') FROM ...` in 1st query.

Comment: I tested using a view @PavelGatnar and although it reduces some writing I'm still having to make the filter by their dates, which is the repeating part now.

Comment: Conditional counting, that sounds nice @Akina, let me give it a try.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  There are probably ways to rewrite the query, but it depends on what the data looks like.  For instance, does the subquery always have a match to the first date in the range?  You have a column names `t.series` which is used for date comparisons.   What it looks like is not obvious.

Comment: @Karol Karol: could you put he original query written by you to the fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use CTEs in MySQL* but you can use [temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) which is a close MySQL equivalent (not sure how you calculate Z so I didn't put that one in):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_t3 AS (
    SELECT t1.created_at, t1.status
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2_id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.t3_id = 1
);

SELECT
    t.series AS week,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_t3 WHERE created_at BETWEEN t.series AND t.series + INTERVAL 6 DAY) X,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_t3 WHERE created_at BETWEEN t.series AND t.series + INTERVAL 6 DAY AND status = 'responded') Y
FROM series_tmp t;
```

*prior to version 8 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: Thanks nzn. What would be the difference between using temporary tables and/or views?

Comment: Off the top of my head: views are just substituting the query (to save you typing it out) but do not not save the results of the query. Temporary tables store the results of your query resulting in more efficient following queries. If you are using joins for example, then views regenerate the join every time you call the query with a different parameter - which can be inefficient. Also - temporary tables can be indexed resulting in very fast access. Views cannot be indexed. Views are usually defined in, and tied to, the DB structure whereas temp tables are usually just defined in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's good to know, I'm gonna test how it goes with temporary tables ;)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that you can pre-aggregate and `JOIN`.  It is not clear what `series` represents, so this will assume it is compatible with the `yearweek()` function:

```
SELECT t.series AS week, t12.X, t12.Y,
       ROUND(( ... ) * 100) / ( ..., AND ... ), 2) Z
FROM series_tmp t LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT YEARWEEK(t1.date) as yw, COUNT(*) as X,
             SUM(t1.some_state = 'x state') as Y
      FROM t1 JOIN 
           t2
           ON t2.id = t1.another_id
      WHERE t2.something = 1
      GROUP BY yw
     ) t12
     ON t12.yw = t.series
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks! I updated the question, there's a fiddle to replicate the scenario. With the dates I don't have problems, I can get the beginning of the week for each of them and then check the rows in the other tables with BETWEEN. I tried the Akina's approach and seems better, but I'm open to any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no subqueries really needed (if I am not missing anything).

```sql
SELECT t.series, 
COUNT(*) AS total,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.status='responded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS respond,
COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.status='responded' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/COUNT(*)*100.0 AS perc

from (
 SELECT '2020-05-31' AS series
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-06-07'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-06-14'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-06-21'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-06-28'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-07-05'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-07-12'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-07-19'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-07-26'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-02'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-09'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-16'
 UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-23'
) AS t
LEFT JOIN  t1 t1 ON t1.created_at BETWEEN t.series AND t.series + INTERVAL 6 DAY
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
GROUP BY t.series
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. As I see with this approach I'd have to manually create the from clause with every date range. I'm gonna give it a look.

Comment: @KarolKarol No, you simply use `series_tmp` instead of the `(SELECT '2020-05-31' AS series...)`